# deleting parent which deleting child jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete only the parent div and keep their children as it is :

```
      <div id="main">
        <div id="1"></div>
        <div id="2"></div>
      </div>
```

How we can delete only the `#main div` without deleting its `children div #1 & #2`?. I tried `detach()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Try [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

```
​$('#main div')​.unwrap();​​​​​​​​​​
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jnCAr/).

Comment: I modified your example so that it visibly changes with `setTimeout`. http://jsfiddle.net/jnCAr/1/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the element with its contents.

```
$('#main').replaceWith($(this).html())
```

Comment: Yes, but don't replace it with its innerHTML.

Comment: believe you want `replaceWith()`